# Load Image Before page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page with two from and two images on this page. When page loads One form submit the page for user verification and redirect back to this page after user verification second form is submitted and site is open. I want to show a welcome message in image format and a waiting image. But my page is submitted before the image load some time. Here is my code of page

```
<?php

    $return_url = "index.php?".$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING];
    $return = base64_encode($return_url);

    $headers = apache_request_headers();

    $date_check1 = date('Y-m-d');
    $date_check2 = date('d-m-Y');

    $auth_confirm = md5('commonauth');

    $contextURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$contextURL .= "s";}
    $contextURL .= "://";
    $http=$contextURL;
    $contextURL = $contextURL.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) $contextURL = $contextURL."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Welcome to a new world of interaction</TITLE>
<style>
.mainimage {background:url("templates/site1/images/Spotlight_Test.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF !important;height:212px;width:612px;}
.waitingimage {background:url("templates/site1/images/ajaxLoader.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF !important;height:43px;width:43px;}
</style>
</HEAD>
<script>
function commonAuth(){
    if(document.referrer == '<?=$http?>authenticationsite.com/'){
        var days = '';

        days = '<?php echo $_REQUEST["passwordExpiration"] ?>';

        if(days > 0){

            document.Form1.submit();
        }else{          
            document.Form2.submit();
        }


    }else{


        if(window.location.hash){
            var hs = window.location.hash;
            var pos = hs.indexOf('#');
            hs = hs.substring(pos+1);
            var hshval = '&hv='+hs;

            document.Form3.returnURL.value = '<?php echo $contextURL; ?>'+hshval;
        }else{
            document.Form3.returnURL.value = '<?php echo $contextURL; ?>';
        }
        document.Form3.submit();
    }

}

</script>
<BODY>
<CENTER>
<div style="margin-top:100px;">
            <div class="mainimage">&nbsp;</div>                   
            <div>
                <span><h1 style="color:#95A1AA;font-size:20px;margin-bottom:5px;font-weight:normal;">Authenticating, please wait.</h1></span>
                <div class="waitingimage">&nbsp;</div>
           </div>
</div>
</CENTER>
<form name=Form3 action="<?=$http?>authenticationsite.com/" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="returnURL" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="failureURL" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="forcePassword" value="" />
</form>
<form name=Form1 action="index.php" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['NTUserID'] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="passwd" value="<?php echo $auth_confirm ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_user" />
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $return?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="2cc1761a4c5bc389d76f95b376bcb07d" value="1" />
</form>
<form name=Form2 action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="qs" value="<?php echo $_SERVER[QUERY_STRING] ?>" />  
</form>
<script>
commonAuth();
</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Call `commonAuth` at page load using `window.onload=commonAuth` instead of calling it at the end of the page. This will make sure the page is loaded fully before calling the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
<script>
commonAuth();
</script>
```

Do this.

```
<script>
window.onload = commonAuth;
</script>
```

Comment: window.onload will slow down my authentication process, and i can not do it.

Answer (score 0):

3 Ways to Preload Images with CSS, JavaScript, or Ajax:

http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/